# Keep trace/span across CompletableFuture in Spring Cloud Sleuth

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, completable-future, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am using Sleuth with `CompletableFuture.handle`. Example:

```
log.info("first");
apnsClient.sendNotification(...).handle((response, cause) -> {
     log.info("second");
});
```

I want the `second` log to have the same trace id as the `first` log. However, it does not. Thus I wonder what to do? Thanks!

P.S. I cannot control how `apnsClient.sendNotification` manage threads (since that is from [Pushy](https://github.com/jchambers/pushy)), so there is no way to use things like [LazyTraceExecutor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/integrations.html#sleuth-async-executor-service-integration).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you can do is retrieve the span (e.g. via `tracer.currentSpan()`) before `log.info("first")`, pass the span to the lambda with `log.info("second")` and manually continue the trace via `tracer.withSpanInScope(span)`. It would look like this:

```
Span span = tracer.currentSpan();
log.info("first");
apnsClient.sendNotification(...).handle((response, cause) -> {
     try (SpanInScope ws = tracer.withSpanInScope(span)) {
         log.info("second");
     }
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much! So should I do this for **every** callback like handle/whenCompleete/...? Or, can Sleuth automatically do some magic, like LazyTraceExecutor or even instrumentation? Thanks!

Comment: @ch271828n open-telemetry does this via instrumentation.

Comment: @Eugene Thanks very much! It seems that this is not supported to spring yet (?) so I will just do it manually as you have provided

Comment: @Marcin Grzejszczak  Do we need to close `SpanInScope` or no? I would like to propagate traceId into completableFuture returned from asyncRabbitTemplate and I don't known when to invoke `close`

Comment: As you can see we did try with resources on withSpanInScope which means that the scope is only opened when log.info happens. You should close the scope before you get out of the thread

Comment: @Eugene Can you provide details on how this is being manually or auto instrumented in Opentelemetry?